# removing blank lines on R

Tags: r, for-loop, na

i am working on a dataset with blanks i would like to remove (i would like to remove the whole line when there is a blank in a column "Code.3"). My dataframe looks like this :

```
Type                  Code.3             CA

Hospit                CH5                50
Hospit                CH6                55
Hospit                ***                10
Hospit                                   115
Amb                   DH7                30
```

i have tried the following code, without success (error message appears) :

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>%
  filter(!Code.3 == missing)
```

As well as a for loop :

```
df_cleaned <- list()
library(dplyr)

 for (i in 1:319){
  if(is_empty(df[i,5]) = TRUE)
   {df <- df[-i,]}
  else{next}
  df_cleaned <- append(df_cleaned, list(df_cleaned, df_cleaned[,5]))
}

df_cleaned
```

Being a beginner on R, im pretty sure my for loop is a disaster. Could anyone help ?

Comment: What does the blank mean? Is it `NA`(missing value in R) or a zero-length string `""`?

Comment: it's just a blank, there is nothing in that column and line in the csv doc in opened on R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we could replace `""` to `NA`and then filter:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Code.3 = na_if(Code.3, "")) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Code.3))
```

Comment: it works, great, thanks ! would you know how to do it with a for loop (im asking by curiosity) ?

Comment: Unfortunately not!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(Code.3 != "")
```

Comment: this does not work unfortunately, the lines are still there...

Comment: can you make your data reproducible so I can check?

Answer (score 1):

`base R` option:

```
df[!apply(df == "", 1, all), ]
```